# image not getting clipped in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

What I have here is that I am saving the source dataURL of images from content script in the storage and retrieving them in the extension script.

I created each image tag with unique ID of the iterating value. 
Then i created a DIV dag and appended the image tag in it.

Problem is that the images are very large in terms of length X breadth and I need to clip them to appropriate size according to the height and width parameter which was retrieved from storage.

When I apply the css property of clipping a rectangle with appropriate values, nothing happens. The image remains of the same size.

Here is the screenshot depicting the same.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot on the right side is showing the size of the div as 1351 X 672 whereas the property of clipping has been applied with size 1321 X 137.

And also the max-height and max-width applied on the div is also not working.

Please help me strip out the extra part of the image.

extension script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("list",function(data){
        var list=data.list;
        for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++) {

            //---------extract some important data stored in the storage----------
            var src=list[i].src;
            var note=list[i].note;
            var height=list[i].height;
            var width=list[i].width;

            //--------------creating image tag-----------
            var img=document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("id","myimg");
            img.setAttribute("src",src);
            img.setAttribute("id",i);

            var div=document.createElement("div");
            div.appendChild(img);
            div.setAttribute("max-height","300px");
            div.setAttribute("max-width","500px");
            div.style.overflow="scroll";

            $("body").append(div);

            $("#"+i).css("clip","rect(0px,"+width+"px,"+height+"px,0px)");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There are no such *HTML* attributes as `max-width` and `max-height`. Use `$(div).css("max-width:500px; max-height:300px")`, also [`clip` was deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip), use `clip-path`, however I'm not sure this is what caused the problem.

Comment: that was stupid of me! max-width and height works fine now. Let me try clip-path too :)

Comment: Also, documentation for `clip` says it requires `position` to be `absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: I tried absolute and fixed position both, but now there is no content to be shown in the extension popup html. The elements are so small that they are not visible.

Comment: @Xan can you think of some other reason or some other way to do this job? I need to be able to clip this image.